# Slick slider "vertical:true, infinite:true" adding whitespace after last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

Settings:

```js
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 1,
arrows: true,
vertical: true,
verticalSwiping: true,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 500,
infinite: true,
dots: false,
adaptiveHeight: true,
```

I am using this configuration for the slider, and when it reaches the last slide it adds some white space and then jumps to the first slide.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the HTML markup of your slideshow and the CSS that's applied to it.

Comment: Please see how to create a [MRE] with the minimum code required to show us the problem you are having, so we can see what is happening and be able to help.